# How to change axis number format in tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a tikzpicture
[image: picture]

but the axis number and y-label is overlapping. Can I change 10^-2 to 0.0x format? Here is the code.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0.75,0.75}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.75,0,0.75}

\begin{axis}[
legend cell align={left},
legend style={draw=white!80.0!black},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
xlabel={iter},
xmin=-0.45, xmax=9.45,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
ylabel={validation loss},
ymin=0.02, ymax=0.15,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\addplot [semithick, blue]
table {%
    0 1.34207456321716
    1 0.174043665003777
    2 0.0967515116870403
    3 0.0754522081717849
    4 0.0627007393673062
    5 0.0568854154974222
    6 0.0532613188970834
    7 0.0480173872113228
    8 0.0488547417262569
    9 0.0495724179415964
};
\addlegendentry{sigmoid}
\addplot [semithick, green!50.0!black]
table {%
    0 0.0815436790004373
    1 0.0580678164817393
    2 0.0577852327806875
    3 0.0555352639421821
    4 0.0451464612137526
    5 0.0502317223999649
    6 0.0461553418475669
    7 0.0499271957382327
    8 0.0516832734428579
    9 0.0523206829108996
};
\addlegendentry{tanh}
\addplot [semithick, red]
table {%
    0 0.0909673798661679
    1 0.0690677527815104
    2 0.047157009664597
    3 0.0472306680250913
    4 0.0443113675033441
    5 0.0446281971708522
    6 0.0425379556572996
    7 0.0536474616983847
    8 0.042482587704694
    9 0.0449555881925859
};
\addlegendentry{ReLU}
\addplot [semithick, color0]
table {%
    0 0.0677304680856876
    1 0.0512181081962772
    2 0.053441882751626
    3 0.0453108992217341
    4 0.0429848205171642
    5 0.0480912580440643
    6 0.0481986717274172
    7 0.0428763461877579
    8 0.0441146830013981
    9 0.045795459733066
};
\addlegendentry{ELU}
\addplot [semithick, color1]
table {%
    0 0.0734140924926382
    1 0.0525769912943244
    2 0.0428529946752125
    3 0.0440804580784636
    4 0.0386188347235729
    5 0.0347992292554467
    6 0.0406374371483398
    7 0.0420104633183742
    8 0.0371617442105591
    9 0.0359923966706483
};
\addlegendentry{Swish}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: If you use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}` in the preamble, the problem does not even arise... and you can change the number format by adding `yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue does not arise with the recent version of pgfplots. Assuming you need to use an older compatibility mode, or you want to change the number format regardless, you could add

```
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed}
```

to the options of your axis.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}%<-also solves the problem
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0.75,0.75}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.75,0,0.75}

\begin{axis}[
legend cell align={left},
legend style={draw=white!80.0!black},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
xlabel={iter},
xmin=-0.45, xmax=9.45,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
ylabel={validation loss},
ymin=0.02, ymax=0.15,
ytick style={color=black},
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed}
]
\addplot [semithick, blue]
table {%
    0 1.34207456321716
    1 0.174043665003777
    2 0.0967515116870403
    3 0.0754522081717849
    4 0.0627007393673062
    5 0.0568854154974222
    6 0.0532613188970834
    7 0.0480173872113228
    8 0.0488547417262569
    9 0.0495724179415964
};
\addlegendentry{sigmoid}
\addplot [semithick, green!50.0!black]
table {%
    0 0.0815436790004373
    1 0.0580678164817393
    2 0.0577852327806875
    3 0.0555352639421821
    4 0.0451464612137526
    5 0.0502317223999649
    6 0.0461553418475669
    7 0.0499271957382327
    8 0.0516832734428579
    9 0.0523206829108996
};
\addlegendentry{tanh}
\addplot [semithick, red]
table {%
    0 0.0909673798661679
    1 0.0690677527815104
    2 0.047157009664597
    3 0.0472306680250913
    4 0.0443113675033441
    5 0.0446281971708522
    6 0.0425379556572996
    7 0.0536474616983847
    8 0.042482587704694
    9 0.0449555881925859
};
\addlegendentry{ReLU}
\addplot [semithick, color0]
table {%
    0 0.0677304680856876
    1 0.0512181081962772
    2 0.053441882751626
    3 0.0453108992217341
    4 0.0429848205171642
    5 0.0480912580440643
    6 0.0481986717274172
    7 0.0428763461877579
    8 0.0441146830013981
    9 0.045795459733066
};
\addlegendentry{ELU}
\addplot [semithick, color1]
table {%
    0 0.0734140924926382
    1 0.0525769912943244
    2 0.0428529946752125
    3 0.0440804580784636
    4 0.0386188347235729
    5 0.0347992292554467
    6 0.0406374371483398
    7 0.0420104633183742
    8 0.0371617442105591
    9 0.0359923966706483
};
\addlegendentry{Swish}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer!